# In many respects meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does ''in many respects'' mean?

''in many respects, important in the sense of capturing the sense that language is
constitutive of history''

'' in many respects my best friends were dogs''

Comment: Don't you mean *in many **aspects***?

Comment: @Ustanak - "In many respects" is a common expression, and certainly correct in the second sentence above. The first sentence seems incomplete - it doesn't make sense as is.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly equivalent to "in many ways".

Observation: it is usually not literally applicable. If you ask the speaker to identify some of the "many ways" in which their claim is true, they will often only be able to point to one or two ways. So it really means the same as "somewhat", or "to some extent", or even "a bit".